# Meaning of 'beware' in this song from the latest WoW trailer

Tags: word-usage, usage

The song has the following lines:

> "Beware, beware the Daughter of the Sea."
>    "Beware," I heard him cry.

And, in the ending:

> To his nation, with his last breath, cried,
>   "Beware the Daughter of the Sea."

Is the meaning of these sentences to warn 'the Daughter of the Sea' (like in 'But beware, dear brother, ...') or to warn **against** her (like in 'Beware the dog')

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fo7XPvwRgG8
Lyrics: https://wow.gamepedia.com/Daughter_of_the_Sea

Answer (score 2):

The complement of **beware** is something you are being warned about.

Be forewarned about the Daughter of the Sea.

The Daughter of the Sea presents a danger of some kind.

You would say

> Beware, brother, the Daughter of the Sea.

or

> Beware, O brother, the Daughter of the Sea.

if you wanted to include the person being given the warning.

The person being warned would not have **the** in front of their name.